# Node.js C++ Binding error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

I am attempting to update a Node.js module's C bindings. I am getting this error:

```
../src/cas.cc: At global scope:
../src/cas.cc:58:18: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
 NAN_WEAK_CALLBACK(casDtor) {
```

The source code is [here](https://github.com/couchbase/couchnode/blob/master/src/cas.cc).

The error can be replicated by cloning the repo and doing an `npm install`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `NAN_WEAK_CALLBACK` macro. Instead there is [`Nan::WeakCallbackInfo`](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/persistent.md#nanweakcallbackinfo) and [`Nan::WeakCallbackType`](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/persistent.md#nanweakcallbacktype-1). There are usage examples in those documentation links.